# Kotlin - Unable to update RecyclerView from fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment (FragmentAdd) with a button which is supposed to update the RecyclerView of another fragment (FragmentHome). Why isn't the RecyclerView updated?

**FragmentAdd:**

```
saveBtn?.setOnClickListener{
    arrayList = getUpdatedList()
    val homeAdapter = HomeAdapter(FragmentHome(),arrayList)
    homeAdapter.updateRecyclerView(arrayList)
}
```

**FragmentHome:**

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    recyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView!!.adapter = HomeAdapter(this, transactList)

    return view
}
```

**HomeAdapter:**

```
fun updateRecyclerView(newList: ArrayList<Any>){
    itemsList.clear()
    itemsList.addAll(newList)
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

I think the issue might be because I'm creating another object of `HomeAdapter` in **FragmentAdd**. If so, how should I make sure it references the original object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues seems to be the creation of multiple **HomeAdapter** instance.

You can create the single object using companion object

In **FragmentAdd**

```
companion object {var homeAdapter:HomeAdapter?=null}
```

Then **FragmentAdd**

```
homeAdapter = HomeAdapter(FragmentHome(),arrayList)
homeAdapter.updateRecyclerView(arrayList)
```

In **FragmentHome**

```
recyclerView!!.adapter=FragmentAdd.homeAdapter!!
```